# I cannot code in Java because there is no leftscreen on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

This is most likely something very basic. Because I am new to Eclipse and Java programming. The window on the left-hand side does not appear for me when I create a new program.

For example here is my screen (it goes no further on the left side, that is it):

[image: screenshot]
http://tinypic.com/r/ztvr79/8

And here is what I would consider a normal one:

Also, I keep getting a warning sign. This is very troubling because I've just started and already am running into this issues. Please help me resolve this.

Thank you

Comment: What does that warning sign say? Also your picture is not visible

Comment: Solution: Use IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Sorry, here's my screen:
http://tinypic.com/r/ztvr79/8

Comment: Window - Show View - Package Explorer. If you want to be a programmer, you shouldn't be afraid of exploring menu items.

Comment: Are you looking for the menu that is usually displayed in default eclipse installs on its left side? Go to "Window"->Show View->Navigator". Also "Package Explorer" might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides kapeps answer you can also show the project or package explorer, whichever you prefer, manually using "Window" -> "Show view" -> "Project Explorer".

What says the warning? If you click on the arrow next to the warning sign, you should see the warning message, source file and line.

Comment: The warning says "Build path specifies execution environment CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1 There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment."

What does that mean?

Comment: This warning just means that your installed JRE is not strictly compatible with the specified execution environment. You can set the targeted execution environment und Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries. Here remove the already inserted one and click on "Add Library" and choose "JRE System Library"

Answer (score 1):

You should reset the "perspective" to get back the default window layout. To do so, right click on the button the top right corner that says "Java" and choose "Reset".